# method identify_finger (pyfrint) returns IndexError

Tags: python

I am using python, the library `pyfprint`, to recognize fingers enrolled and `pymongo` for data storage

```
def identificar_digital():
dev.open()
impressoes = []
lista = funcionarios.find()

for i in range(lista.count()):
    func = lista.next()
    with fs.get(func.get('digital')) as fp_read:
        data = pyfprint.pyf.fp_print_data_from_data(str(fp_read.read()))
        impressoes.append(pyfprint.Fprint(data_ptr = data))

# Corrigir problema no retorno: IndexError: list index out of range
off, fp, fp_img = dev.identify_finger(impressoes)
dev.close()
return fp
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ponto.py", line 79, in <module>
    fp = identificar_digital()
  File "ponto.py", line 37, in identificar_digital
    off, fp, fp_img = dev.identify_finger(impressoes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyfprint/pyfprint.py", line 267, in identify_finger
    return (offset, fprints[offset], img)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Could you please fix your indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. Something in the current version of libfprint it's broken. I used the version 0.5.0 and works normally

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code here, https://github.com/luksan/pyfprint/blob/master/pyfprint/pyfprint.py you can see exactly where the problem lies.

`fprints` is a list of finger prints. `offset` is returned by `pyf.pyfp_identify_finger_img()`. You are obviously getting a `pyf.FPVERIY_MATCH` however the offset being returned is incorrect. You should check what offset is being returned. You could use the Python debugger, `pdb` for instance.

If you see at the top of the identify_finger function there is a `FIXME: error handling` comment. The developer of this module has plainly said that he does not handle errors that's why you get an unhandled exception.

Comment: Thanks, William. You're right. offset return the value "139977279143936", but I dont understand the reason. I gonna investigate